# Game Center Set Up OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, game-center

I'm trying to play a game that I just bought that uses the Game Center on OS X Mountain Lion. This is the first time I have a game that uses the Game Center. I'm able to log in with my Apple ID. It asks me to set up my Game Center account. I choose create a nickname and I check the tick-boxes if I want want my profile public or not and to add my contacts. After I click continue I get a window that says saving but it never saves, never gives an error message. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 3):

I was having the exact same problem. I was picking my true nickname (lizzie) and it just kept spinning and spinning and never would save. So, I decided to try a nickname I KNEW no one would have (my name spelled backwards). It saved immediately. Maybe your nickname is too common? Try something truly unique. Hope that works for you.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Too bad they can't tell you up front that your nickname is not good.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I tried one nickname but the cursor just kept spinning and the screen said "saving...". I then tried a very uncommon nickname that I was pretty sure no one else had and the signing in worked. Apple needs to fix this signing in process so that GC tells you that a nickname is already used rather than going round and round.